# How to insert a line break in a string literal ES6

Tags: ecmascript-6

Hello I have a method where I have to print address in this format:-

```
AddressLine1,
City, State
```

In other words I want a line break after AddressLine1.

So I have a method like this:-

```
const getAddress = pursuit => {
  if(pursuit.address!=null){
    const addressLine1 = pursuit.address.addressLine1;
    const cityState = `${pursuit.address.addressCity}, ${pursuit.address.addressState.value}`;
    return `${addressLine1},\n 
            ${cityState}`;
  } 
  return '';
};
```

But it doesn't give me the desired result.

Comment: In template strings actually you don't need line break \n, simply 'enter' is not working ?

Comment: HTML elements won't respect `\n` unless you set `white-space: pre-wrap;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having issues because you are already inserting a line break and leading whitespace in your template string. To achieve your desired result, you can just have the `\n`, that is, everything on a single line:

```
const getAddress = pursuit => {
  if(pursuit.address!=null){
    const addressLine1 = pursuit.address.addressLine1;
    const cityState = `${pursuit.address.addressCity}, ${pursuit.address.addressState.value}`;
    return `${addressLine1},\n${cityState}`;
  } 
  return '';
};
```

A shorter and runnable example:

```js
const part1 = 'A long text that'
const part2 = 'continues below';
const longText = `${part1}\n${part2}`;

console.log(longText);
```

Comment: Paste `longText` as `innerHTML` into a `div` or `p`. You'll see the line-break is not respected by the browser.